# Is there a javascript/Node.js library for accessing the Alchemy Data News API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I've looked in the watson-developer-cloud package and its namesake namespace on GitHub.  Will I need to go directly to the REST API in my app?

Comment: [Here](http://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/tree/master/services/alchemy_data_news)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access all the Watson and Alchemy APIs using the [`watson-developer-cloud`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-developer-cloud#alchemy-data-news) npm module.

1. Install the npm module.

   ```
   $ npm install watson-developer-cloud
   ```
2. Get an Alchemy API key from [Bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/).
3. Create a `test.js` file with the content below

   ```
   var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');

   var alchemy_data_news = watson.alchemy_data_news({
     api_key: '<api_key>'
   });

   var params = {
     start: 'now-1d',
     end: 'now'
   };

   alchemy_data_news.getNews(params, function (err, news) {
     if (err)
       console.log('error:', err);
     else
       console.log(JSON.stringify(news, null, 2));
   });
   ```

Comment: I swear I tried that before asking the question and it didn't work.  But it works now!  Thanks @german-attanasio